# AWS SAM template deployed docker but failed in BUILD and POST_BUILD. when building on aws codebuild getting this error: exit status 125

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-codebuild, aws-sam-cli

Trying to build docker container using aws sam through cloudformation template. when my code is building on aws codebuild i'm getting this error: Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -t ${APPLICATION_NAME}:latest .. Reason: exit status 125

i removed - from the application name after seeing docker app naming convention. but nothing has changed.